# Why do I get the error: "Vue3CalendarHeatmap is missing template or render function"?

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to put my github heatmap inside a vue3 component.
To do so, I've tried using the vue3-calendar-heatmap (https://razorness.github.io/vue3-calendar-heatmap/) module. To test the module, I'm trying the following code:

(file: GitHubHeatmap.vue)

```js
<template>
    <div class="heatmap">
        <Vue3CalendarHeatmap :values="heatmapData" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Vue3CalendarHeatmap from 'vue3-calendar-heatmap';

    export default {
        name: 'GitHubHeatmap',
        components: {
            Vue3CalendarHeatmap
        },
        data() {
            return {
                heatmapData: [{ date: "2021-01-01", count: 0 }],
                heatmapColors: ['#3b1610', '#67271e', '#973a2c', '#ca4e39', '#ff6347'],
                username: "mrbigoudi",
            };
        }
    };
</script>
```

However, even with that simple example, no heatmap is visible in the page (though the rest of the page is loading fine) and I get the following warning when running with `npm run dev`:

```
[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function. 
  at <Vue3CalendarHeatmap values= [{…}]0: 
                        {date: "2021-01-01", count: 0}
                        length: 1
                        __proto__: Array(0) > 
  at <GitHubHeatmap> 
  at <About> 
  at <App>
warn2                   @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:40
finishComponentSetup    @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:7402
setupStatefulComponent  @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:7298
setupComponent          @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:7220
mountComponent          @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5542
processComponent    @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5517
patch                   @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5119
mountChildren           @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5303
mountElement            @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5213
processElement          @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5196
patch                   @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5116
componentUpdateFn   @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5656
run                 @   reactivity.esm-bundler.js:190
instance.update         @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5763
setupRenderEffect   @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5777
mountComponent          @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5559
processComponent    @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5517
patch                   @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5119
mountChildren           @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5303
mountElement            @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5213
processElement          @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5196
patch                   @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5116
mountChildren           @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5303
mountElement            @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5213
processElement          @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5196
patch                   @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5116
componentUpdateFn   @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5656
run                 @   reactivity.esm-bundler.js:190
instance.update         @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5763
setupRenderEffect   @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5777
mountComponent          @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5559
processComponent    @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5517
patch                   @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5119
mountChildren           @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5303
mountElement            @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5213
processElement          @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5196
patch                   @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5116
componentUpdateFn   @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5656
run                 @   reactivity.esm-bundler.js:190
instance.update         @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5763
setupRenderEffect   @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5777
mountComponent          @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5559
processComponent    @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5517
patch                   @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5119
render2                 @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6278
mount                   @   runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4474
app.mount           @   runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1607
(anonymous)         @   main.js?t=1683590947644:5
```

I've also tried with an ':end-date' attribute since it's written as 'required' in the doc (https://razorness.github.io/vue3-calendar-heatmap/)

PS: since it appears in the warning, here is my main.js file

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './index.css'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use named import `{CalendarHeatmap}` when using bundler:

```
import { CalendarHeatmap } from "vue3-calendar-heatmap";
   export default {
    name: 'GitHubHeatmap',
    components: {
        CalendarHeatmap 
    },
     data() {
        return {
            heatmapData: [{ date: "2021-01-01", count: 0 }]
    }
}
```

Here is the working snippet without a bundler. However, this example uses `umd` module, because prebuilt `esm` module from CDN had issues (Cannot read property 'isCE') as described [here](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4344)

```html
  <div id="app">
    <calendar-heatmap
      :values="heatmapData"
      :end-date="'2021-06-22'"
      :range-color="heatmapColors"
    />
  </div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
 <script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue3-cal-hm@1.0.6/dist/vue3-cal-hm.umd.min.js "></script>
  <script>
    const app = Vue.createApp({
      components: { 'calendar-heatmap': CalendarHeatmap.CalendarHeatmap  },
      data() {
        return {
          heatmapData: [{ date: "2021-01-01", count: 10 },{ date: "2021-01-02", count: 20 }],
          heatmapColors: ["#3b1610", "#67271e", "#973a2c", "#ca4e39", "#ff6347"],
          username: "mrbigoudi",
        };
      },
    });
    app.mount('#app');
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine ! I just also needed to remove the '0' before any elements of the dates (for example '2021-06-22' becomes '2021-6-22') otherwise I have an 'Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode' error